# MVC5 with attribute routing: how to get route data associated with particular action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

Let's assume I have an `ActionDescriptor` (or `MethodInfo`) object that points to some action method in my application. I want to get route table's entries (`System.Web.Routing.Route` objects) associated with this action.

Is there, by any chance, some framework method that might get me this information, or do I have to parse the route table somehow? How would you suggest to do this, in the second case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how I did this:

```
var routeProvider = new DefaultDirectRouteProvider();
var routeEntries = routeProvider.GetDirectRoutes(
    _actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor, new[] { _actionDescriptor }, new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver());
```